# args[0]==null Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at Main.main(Main.java:69)

Tags: java, args

Trying to call the java file, and have been asked to make it so that if args[0] is empty in a terminal call, it should return all objects. Cant get it working without getting an error.

```
else if(args[1]==null){
            System.out.println("Printing information on all cars.");
                for (Bil l : bilArrayList){
                    System.out.println(l.toString());
                }

        }
```

Comment: args[0] or args[1] ?

Comment: Please include the full `main()` method along with the number of parameters you passed in to get this error message. Obviously, if you only passed in one parameters then your code snippet would cause problems.

Comment: Well both, args[0] is the name of the file, such as "1.txt" while args[1] contains the instances of the objects that are to be printed.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your code, I would suggest you to check the size of `args` first:

```
if(args.length> 0) { 
//It depends on the size of the argument you wanna check. 
//Might be args.length > 1 if you wanna make sure at least 2 elements in the args array
   //doSomething
} else {
  //doSomethingElse
}
```

Comment: args[1] means the second value, so you should check args.length > 1 if you want to get args[1]. Please note that you have args[0] and then args[1]

Comment: @Piotr0123456 the OP's requirement looks bit confusing. In the question it said "if args[0] is empty in a terminal call, it should return all objects". But  the code checks `args[1]`.

Comment: yes, I agree that "the OP's requirement looks bit confusing". The full `main()` method would be very helpful here. We don't know the details...